# Table view cell as button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to set a Table View Cell that has been grouped, as a button however I can't seem to find where to do it in the interface builder in XCode 4.2 or programmatically.

I've tried linking the table view cell to an IBAction, however it only lets me create or link to an IBOutlet.

As a temporary fix I have embedded a rectangle button in the cell, but this doesn't highlight blue when pressed.

I've seen this work in several apps, an example is the Clear History and Clear Cookies and Data buttons in the Safari app below:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagine that your IBAction is like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed{
//Do my stuff
}
```

Then, you should do this in your delegate:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //check if your cell is pressed
    BOOL myCellIsPressed = ...

     if(myCellIsPressed)
        [self buttonPressed];
}
```

To check if your cell was pressed, you have several ways, for example, if you know the row of your button in the table:

```
int myCellRow = 5;
if (myCellRow == IndexPath.row) //YES!
```

Or you can put a tag in your cell and then check if is that one:

```
#define myTag 5
```

When creating the cell:

```
UITableViewCell *myCell = ...
myCell.tag = myTag
```

And in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (selectedCell.tag == myTag) //YES!
```

Comment: A very simple question, but how does the didSelectRowAtIndexPath know which cell or row was actually pressed? I get the BOOL is to check that it WAS pressed, but how does it know which one?

Comment: absolutely brilliant response, thank you very much tonio. One final question to be clear: does IndexPath.row represent what ever the user has pressed? so when you say myCellRow == IndexPath.row, is that saying if the cell that is pressed called myCellRow then do something?

Comment: Yes, that's it!. You are welcome, dont forget to mark the answer as solved, and I hope to help you in the future!

Answer (score 1):

these aren't buttons..
The function of clear cookies and other things are processed in 
table view delegate method

```
 tableview : didselectRow
```

There you can find which section and which row is selected and perform functions based on that.