# Using UITableViewCell of a Section to trigger an IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ibaction

I've a `tableView` with 2 sections. One section has only one `row` with the titleLabel that displays date. I'm using [Action Sheet Picker](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) to display the Action Sheet.
So In my view controller I've declared an object of `DateTableViewCell *dateCell;` and here are my delegate and data source method of that table view:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Date";
    }
    else
    {
        return @"Select Location to View Schedule";
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 5;
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"locationCell";
    HomeLocationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             cellIdentifier];

    static NSString *dateCellIdentifier = @"dateCell";
    dateCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                                       dateCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HomeLocationTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    else if (dateCell == nil)
    {
        dateCell = [[DateTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:dateCellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {
        dateCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
        return dateCell;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.locationNameLabel.text = @"ABC Hospital";
        cell.totalAppointmentLabel.text = @"15 Appointments";
        return cell;
    }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {
        [dateCell targetForAction:@selector(selectADate:) withSender:self];
        //[self performSelector:@selector(selectADate:) withObject:dateCell];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
}
```

Ignore Section 1 as it's just the demo data. So this is how I'm adding date to the cell and as you can see in did select row for index path I'm calling the method below but it's not being called. I've tried it with both the commented and the un-commented line.

```
- (void)selectADate:(UIControl *)sender {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *minimumDateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [minimumDateComponents setYear:2000];
    NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:minimumDateComponents];
    NSDate *maxDate = [NSDate date];


    _actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:self.selectedDate
                                                               target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:) origin:sender];


    [(ActionSheetDatePicker *) self.actionSheetPicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
    [(ActionSheetDatePicker *) self.actionSheetPicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];

    [self.actionSheetPicker addCustomButtonWithTitle:@"Today" value:[NSDate date]];
    [self.actionSheetPicker addCustomButtonWithTitle:@"Yesterday" value:[[NSDate date] TC_dateByAddingCalendarUnits:NSCalendarUnitDay amount:-1]];
    self.actionSheetPicker.hideCancel = YES;
}

- (void)dateWasSelected:(NSDate *)selectedDate element:(id)element {
    self.selectedDate = selectedDate;

    //may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
    dateCell.dateLabel.text = [self.selectedDate description];
}
```

If I try  `- (IBAction)selectADate:(UIControl *)sender` instead of what I'm using right now it tells me to connect it to something and I want to connect it to Cell but there is no such connection possible even if I try to implement it `UITableViewCell` class.

Comment: Why do you need sender?

Comment: what would be the sender in this case? is it cell ?

Comment: @Mr.UB I don't need it. I just what didSelect to open pickerview and give set the dateLabel to whatever user has selected.

Comment: Okay so you want to set the date for the cell selected?

Comment: @Mr.UB yes! and there will always be one cell in that section... so yes

Answer (score 0):

you can make your method something like,

```
  - (void)selectADate:(UITableViewCell *)cell {


    // your method body!
  }
```

and call that method from `didselectRowAtindexpath` like,

```
  YorTableViewCellClass *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self selectADate:cell];
```

**Update :**

Remove sender from `selectADate` method so it looks like,

```
   - (void)selectADate{

    }
```

second thing replace below line,

```
    _actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:self.selectedDate
                                                           target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:) origin:sender];
```

with

```
    _actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:self.selectedDate
                                                           target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:) origin:self.view];
```

I have used `self.view` instead of `sender`.

Comment: with you changes and my method implementation as in my question of `selectADate` the `@selector(dateWasSelected:element:)` is not being called in the init method of `ActionSheetDatePicker`

Comment: okay. Thats why i ask first in comment that what would be the sender !!! I am updating my answer if it works!!

Comment: Sorry I missed you comment up there... answering it here! The sender would be the cell in this case I guess. But I don't really need a sender if there is another way. As there is only one cell in that section and when it did get selected I want to show picker view.

Comment: nope still the same... What is happening is that it goes into the `selectADate` method executes it completely but didn't show ActionPicker and didn't go to `dateWasSelected` method.

Comment: but where are you showing `actionpicker` btw ? and why you not using native `UIDatePicker` of ios if you just want to pick date?

Comment: As there are some UITextFields like gender where I want to show customized pickerView so someone suggested me https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0 that is why. It works great with UITextField but as I m trying to configure it with cell I'm stuck.

Comment: If you only want to show datepicker and pick date then don't use this third party library!! it can be achieved by native methods easily!!

Answer (score 0):

For create action,

[Table view cell as button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530984/table-view-cell-as-button)

Visit this link, Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Create an IBAction of the button in your custom Cell `HomeLocationTableViewCell`. Implement a protocol in your cell and set the view controller (which implements datasource and delegate of your table view) its delegate.

Now when the action is triggered send your delegate a message that cell wants to select a date. Pass your cell in delegate message so that your delegate can set its date label upon selection.

In your `HomeLocationTableViewCell.h
@protocol HomeLocationTableViewCellDelegate
- (void)homeLocationTableViewCell:(HomeLocationTableViewCell *)cell didTapDateButton;
@end` 
and in your viewController in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
`cell.delegate = self`

Then Implement this delegate method in your viewController

`- (void)homeLocationTableViewCell:(HomeLocationTableViewCell *)cell didTapDateButton { 
//show your action sheet here and use this cell to set its label
}`

Comment: Not an appropriate approach as the Cell doesn't need a UIButton.

Comment: Thats the whole point of customising UITableViewCell. As per Apple Docs you can add subviews in UITableViewCell. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell